# Finding key value in map

Tags: c++

I am using an iterator in a for loop to traverse a map that has keys of type int. How would I be able to access the value of the key at the specific iteration, so that I can use it later?

Comment: You can find the key faster using one of map's find functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dereferencing the iterator gives you a key-value pair, `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>`.

So to get the key from the iterator, get the first element of the pair:

```
key_type key = it->first;
```